# Adding attributes to XML nodes with PowerShell adds namespaces

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to add some attributes to some newly created XML nodes using PowerShell but for some reason the attributes look like this:

```xml
<add d5p1:name="" d5p2:value="" xmlns:d5p2="noindex,nofollow" xmlns:d5p1="X-Robots-Tag" />
```

Any ideas why it is formatting the attributes like this with namespaces?  My code is quite simple:

```
if ($node -ne $null) {
    $node.SetAttributeNode("name", "X-Robots-Tag")
    $node.SetAttributeNode("value", "noindex,nofollow")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03b7fb27.aspx). The `SetAttributeNode()` method adds a namespaced attribute without value.

> ```
> public virtual XmlAttribute SetAttributeNode(
>     string localName,
>     string namespaceURI
> )
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> *localName*
>   Type: System.String
>   The local name of the attribute.
>
> *namespaceURI*
>   Type: System.String
>   The namespace URI of the attribute.
>
> [...]
>
> **Remarks**
>   The `XmlAttribute` does not have any children. Use `Value` to assign a text value to the attribute or use `AppendChild` (or a similar method) to add children to the attribute.

You're looking for the [`SetAttribute()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1ah1zbw.aspx) method.

```
if ($node -ne $null) {
    $node.SetAttribute("name", "X-Robots-Tag")
    $node.SetAttribute("value", "noindex,nofollow")
}
```